# How to get just current average temperature from wttr.in curl result with bash?

Tags: bash, curl, grep, tmux

[wttr.in](http://wttr.in/) can give you the weather by curling wttr.in:

```
curl wttr.in/Amsterdam
```

I returns a large list of data and I want to use it as a tmux segment, so I've narrowed it down to just the first mention of temperature (which is the current temperature):

```
curl wttr.in/Amsterdam | grep -m 1 °C
```

Which sometimes returns a range:

```
_ /"".-.     4 – 7 °C
```

And sometimes a single temperature:

```
_ /"".-.     13 °C
```

So there's still some garbage in front of it, and it sometimes returns a range instead of a single temperature. Does anyone know how I can narrow this down to always return a single temperature (averaged if there's two values) and without the preceding text?

Comment: Just removing all characters up until the first number would already be a huge improvement btw. I tried doing it with `cut` but couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

wttr.in now supports [one-line output](https://github.com/chubin/wttr.in#one-line-output) with custom format, so this

```
curl wttr.in/Amsterdam?format=%t
```

returns just the temperature, and as far as I can tell, it returns a single value instead of a range.

---

#### Previous version of answer

<sub>Based on the assumption that we have to modify the response ourselves</sub>

The main difficulty with this is that the service returns terminal escape codes, which make it messy to process. This is what you *really* get:

```
$ curl -s wttr.in/Amsterdam | grep -m 1 '°.' | cat -A
 ^[[38;5;226m _ /""^[[38;5;250m.-.    ^[[0m ^[[38;5;048m5^[[0m M-bM-^@M-^S ^[[38;5;046m8^[[0m M-BM-0C^[[0m       $
```

which renders like this:

[image: Rendered output from wttr.in]

Because of this, we can't just extract everything from the first number on, because that would include almost the whole line due to the escape sequences.

Fortunately, we can tell wttr.in to not send us the colour escapes using the `T` query string parameter (hat tip to [keheliya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/469794/keheliya) for pointing this out):

```
$ curl -s wttr.in/Amsterdam?T | grep -m 1 '°.' | cat -A
  _ /"".-.     5-8 M-BM-0C         $
```

Now we can extract everything from the first digit encountered on, using `grep -o` (retains only the match). This also takes into account that there could be a minus sign for negative temperatures:

```
curl -s wttr.in/Amsterdam?T | grep -m 1 '°.' | grep -Eo -e '-?[[:digit:]].*'
```

or, in a single grep expression:

```
curl -s wttr.in/Amsterdam?T | grep -m 1 -Eo -e '-?[[:digit:]].*°.+'
```

The output of this is

```
5–8 °C
```

Now, if you want just the average if you get a range, you could write a function like this:

```
cur_temp () {
    # Get current temperature into variable
    local cur=$(curl -s wttr.in/Amsterdam?T \
        | grep -m 1 -Eo -e '-?[[:digit:]].*°.')

    # Check if it is a range
    if [[ $cur == *..* ]]; then

        # Use regex to extract temperature values
        local re='(-?[[:digit:]]+)\.\.([[:digit:]]+).*°(.)'
        [[ $cur =~ $re ]]
        local lower=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
        local upper=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
        local unit=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}

        # Calculate average (truncates to integers)
        cur="$(( (lower + upper) / 2 )) °$unit"
    fi

    echo "$cur"
}
```

If we call this function on a result that previously returned a range, we just get the average now (truncated to integers):

```
$ cur_temp
6 °C
```

Non-ranges are the same as before.

This can be parameterized for location, just like in the example function that you get from `wttr.in/:bash.function`.

Comment: Or, use `curl -A "Mozilla/5.0" wttr.in/Amsterdam` and process the returned HTML instead of the terminal escape sequences...

Comment: This is great. I really need to study sed and regexes more. Only thing I added btw was `sed -e 's/[[:space:]]*$//'` to trim the trailing whitespace. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Appending `?T` to the URL gets rid of terminal sequences. See http://wttr.in/:help for more information.

Comment: wttr.in changed the formatting of their temperature display from "10-15 °<unit>" to "10..15 °<unit>". I have submitted an edit to update the script to handle this.

Comment: @CodeFriendly Thanks! I've "improved" it by removing the curly braces around `unit`, but that's just my personal preference. Shows up as approved in the edit history for you, in any case.

Answer (score 1):

I could add Temp, H, P and Wind with this simple line at my i3block:

```
[weather]
full_text=
command=curl wttr.in/-31.82,-60.52\?format\="%t%20|%20%h%20|%20%P%20|%20%w"
interval=1800
```

It's a spartan beauty:

[image: wttr_i3Blocks image]